# What should my vs.code settings file look like using cypress typescipt and cucumber

Tags: json, typescript, cucumber, cypress

I've cloned this repo because I'd like to play around using cypress and cucumber.

https://github.com/eccanto/base-cypress-cucumber-typescript

However after installing the cucumber full support extension and doing npm i. I can't seem to get the glue to work on the feature file. Or in this case autocomplete.

Here is my settings.json any ideas?

```
{
    // Specify the directory where your step definitions are located
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
      "cypress/e2e/steps/src/pages/*.ts",
      "cypress/e2e/steps/src/*.ts"
    ],
  
    // Enable strict Gherkin completion, ensuring consistent step definitions
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
  
    // Specify custom parameters to pass to your step definitions
    "cucumberautocomplete.customParameters": [
  
    ],
  
    // Define the directory where your feature files are located
    "cucumber.features": [
      "cypress/e2e/features"
    ],

    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "cypress/e2e/features",
  
    // Set your preferred icon theme for the editor
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  }
```